# Why are all dictionary key values being updated instead of just the one I am specifying?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with dates as key names:

```
dateDict = dict.fromkeys(newDateRange,[])
```

Out:

```
{'2021-02-09': [], '2021-02-08': []}
```

I also have the following class:

```
class attendance:
    def matchDate(self):
        if self.datein date_dict:
        date_dict[self.date].extend(self.names)
            
    def __init__(self, names, date):
        self.tickers = names
        self.date= date
```

My idea is to have an object with the same format in self.date as a key name in dateDict. For example, self.date would be '2021-02-09', and somewhere in dateDic is a key also called '2021-02-09'. However, whenever I run my code, the object updates both keys with its values instead of the one I am trying to specify.

In:

```
whosHere = attendance(['Billy','Kyle','Joe','Ashley'], '2021-02-09')
whosHere.matchDate()

dateDict
```

Out:

```
{'2021-02-09': ['Billy','Kyle','Joe','Ashley'], '2021-02-08': ['Billy','Kyle','Joe','Ashley']}
```

Instead of just:

```
{'2021-02-09': ['Billy','Kyle','Joe','Ashley'], '2021-02-08': []}
```

Comment: Each dictionary key has *exactly the same list* as its value.  `dict.fromkeys()` is basically useless with a mutable value for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.from_keys()` is using the same list as the value of all the keys.

Use a dictionary comprehension instead.

```
dateDict = {key: [] for key in newDateRange}
```

Comment: That does make sense now. Thank you!